Definition of expectation based on point function $u$ and set function $F$

From chapter $IV.2$ of $$\textit{William Feller 'An Introduction 
to Probability Theory 
and Its Applications'; Vol.2}$$
In $(2.1)$, it's given this integral and it's noted that the probability of a general domain $A$ is denoted by $E(1_A)\;$($1_A$ is the indicator function of $A$), but now, I don't understand how does the interval function apply to this context, because by this notation, I'd be inclined to think that $dx$ is a $1$-dimensional interval, but if we were integrating in $\mathfrak{R^r}$, then this set function would be a function of $r$-dimensional intervals. Is just a matter of notation or a misunderstanding of mine?

Basically $dx$ is a notation representing the "infinitesimal volume" measured by the variable $x$ in the general measurable space e.g. $\mathbb R^n$, not only in $\mathbb R$. What is the definition of interval function?

Presumable an interval function is a measure on $\mathbb{R}^r$.
